# Saving the output of a function

Tags: python, function

I want to change the value of a variable through a function but python functions do not modify a variable when run. For example:

```
import random as r
x=2
def add(x):
   x=x+r.randint(5,10)
   print x
add(x)
print x
```

the function variable x, shows something like 8 while the other x is 2. Adding the line:

```
x=add()
```

will cause the two to be nonequivalent. How can i save the variable from a function, modifying the old.

Comment: your `add` functions always returns `None`

Comment: yes i forgot to insert 'x' in add()

Comment: functions implicitly `return None` at the end if you don't return anything. You need to have a `return x` at the end of your function

Comment: Do those two comments solve your problem?  You have to send in the input argument, return the appropriate value, and assign that to a local variable.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I recommend that you not use the name `x` both for the variable you create outside the function and for the parameter inside the function. Even though you named them both `x`, they are two distinct variables. The Python compiler has no problem telling which is which, but since you are just learning Python, this can be confusing. It may help you understand the code if you rename one of them, for example you might use `value` instead of `x` inside the function.

Comment: In addition (pun intended), I would suggest _not_ storing the result of your calculation back into the input variable, but instead creating a new variable if you don't want to just return the value directly. So your `add` function might be `def add(value): return value + r.randint(5,10)` if you return the value directly, or `def add(value): result = value + r.randint(5,10); print(result); return result` if you want to save it in a variable and keep the `print` statement. (I can't do code formatting in a comment, so change the `;` to newlines in your code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change you function like this :

```
    import random as r
x=2
def add(x):
   x=x+r.randint(5,10)
   print (x)
   return (x)
x=add(x)
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Your add function, this will also return None. Using no return at all, that value is not meant to be used or caught. It simply means that the function ended successfully. It's basically the same as return in void functions in languages such as C++ or Java.